# Add site to Internet Explorer Security Zone in GP without deleting all other settings

Tags: group-policy, internet, dns-zone, explorer

What I have figured out is this:

GP:

User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Internet Explorer -> Internet Control Panel -> Site to Zone Assignment list.

If I enable it, and add a site with the value 2, All my users gets this in their settings as allowed.

Problem is that this deletes all users previous zone settings.

Anyone have any idea on how I can avoid this?